# What are the MB files that delphi 7 generates?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

In the delphi 7 project folders a lot of *.Mb files are generated. The files are named like Del1.MB, Del2.MB etc. The projects connect to firebird databases via the BDE. Also there are quite a few other non standard components being used. Does anyone know what these MB files are and if they can be safely deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these "del*.mb" files are temp BDE PARADOX format files, by default BDE creates them in the application folder and delete them on application close:

http://www.borlandtalk.com/image-vp141388.html

http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-pascal-delphi-databases/212042-bde-generating-del-mb-files.html

Comment: I find the fact that this is the 21st century and there are people that still use paradox quite funny...

Answer (score 3):

These DEL*.MB files as well as DEL*.DB files are created automatically by Borland Database Engine (BDE)[1](http://mc-computing.com/Databases/BDE.html) components for data access, for example when a query (by TQuery component) run.

They are temporary files, so they will be removed automatically if the BDE session terminates correctly[2](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/89/51475.html). If some app crashes these files will be held until the next execution when most of them will be replaced, so, a manual cleaning may be necessary.

If the folder where these files are being created is shared (or an app changed its current dir to same folder, e.g. by use of SetCurrentDir function), it may cause more problems since different apps may lock files making other apps confused and causing other crashes.

Comment: You j*did* notice that this post was 6 years old, right?

Comment: If the response is not under the policies, it should be removed. If it is not contributing or the question is not interesting anymore, the audiance will ignore it by themselves.

Comment: And the question has already received an accepted answer that says the same thing you did. But OK. Have  it your way.